# Constant Strings?

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation

I am writing a workbook to compute double integrals, and in order to graph the function in polar/cylindrical form, I have to make a substitution in the original formula. How can I have the original output in a string, and then changed. Below is a snippet of essentially what is want to do.

```
Input["Input the function f(r,theta)", function];
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
function (*this would output as r*)
Plot3D[function,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}] (*this would have the substitution made*)
```

Or, If a function could be defined (a topic I am hopelessly lost on) that would graph in Cylindrical Coordinates (r,theta,z) , something in the form below, to eliminate my above problem, that would be just as welcome

```
 PolarPlot3D[F[r_,theta_],{r,rmin,rmax},{theta,thetamin,thetamax}]
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question, but would [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) or [`RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) perhaps help with what you want to accomplish?

Comment: [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) would work: `Plot3D[function /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`